# Animating unknown number of items

Tags: animation, angular

I have a div with x images in it aligned horizontally. The div is only showing one image at a time. When I press a button I want to animate the items until the next image is visible. I tried using animation triggers but since I could have unknown number of images I don't know how to change the translate variable within the trigger. When I set state to 'in' it animates once to -100% but I want it to continue to animate to the next image when I click the button again. So for the third image I would need to change the translateX to -200%.
Is there a way to do it, or another way to handle this kind of animation?

```
trigger('animateX', [
        state('in', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
        transition('start => in', [
            style({
                transform: 'translateX(0%)'
            }),
            animate('0.2s ease-in')
        ])
    ])
```

The template....

```
 <div class="carousel">
    <ul class="images">
        <li [@animateX]="state">
    <img src="myImage1" />
        </li>
        <li [@animateX]="state">
    <img src="myImage2" />
        </li>
        <li [@animateX]="state">
    <img src="myImage3" />
        </li>
<ul >
```

[UPDATE] I would like to add a forward and back buttons which animate the carousel into the corresponding direction. So far I have the following trigger and it works ok except for two cases:

1. If I press next and then I press the back button the new item appears correctly but the current item leaves into the wrong direction. If I press back again then it is ok. It's only when switching the states from next to prev and vice versa.
2. When showing the carousel initially I don't want any animation to occur. The carousel should simply show the first item.

Here is the trigger code and below it a plunkr from @micronyks

```
     trigger('animateX', [            
        state('next', style({})),
        transition('* => next', [
            style({ transform: 'translatex(100%)' }),
            animate(300)
        ]),
        transition('next => void', [
            animate(300, style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
        ]),

        state('prev', style({})),
        transition('* => prev', [
            style({ transform: 'translatex(-100%)' }),
            animate(300)
        ]),
        transition('prev => void', [
            animate(300, style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
        ])
    ])
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SS3nb7bkl3YBMoViDsRz?p=preview

Comment: what's wrong with this code? what is not working? what you expect? can you show more code where you actually use `[@animateX]`?

Comment: Hi @micronyks see the added code. When I set state to 'in' it animates once to -100% but I want it to continue to animate for the next image. So I would need to change the translateX to -200% and so on

Comment: Can we use `ngFor` in this to show imgs?

Comment: Hi yes, using ngFor would be fine. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Yes I have. https://plnkr.co/edit/LtnqKnUuURuzw7KKN0na?p=preview. If it suits to your requirement. i'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @micronyks thanks for your solution it works well. One more thing, I was trying to figure out how to prevent the first item to animate in the beginning, so basically it should already be visible.

Comment: @micronyks I updated my question, I would like to add a next and back buttons. I used your plunkr and added states to the trigger. Please see in the question...

Comment: I can't see any updated code in plunker.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had some problems updating the code in plunkr and the  web server went down. But I update the question with the trigger code and I added a prevValue method with --this.next;

Comment: Still I can't see any updated code.

Comment: What I meant is that I had problems editing the plunkr and didn´t succeed. The plunkr website was very slow when updating my code in the end the plunkr web server went down so I had to start over.. Maybe you can copy the updated code at the bottom of my question?

Comment: Hi @micronyks , thanks for your help. So I got the plunkr working and if you test it you will see when you press next and then prev or otherway around the animation for the leaving item is going into the wrong direction on first click after that it's ok. Here is the plunk 'http://plnkr.co/edit/SS3nb7bkl3YBMoViDsRz?p=preview'